# Можно ли узнать контекст переданной функции?

Tags: javascript

Например:

```js
function test( func ) {
  // можно ли здесь узнать контекст переданной ф-ии?
}

function whoami() { }
const ctxA = { name: "A" };
const ctxB = { name: "B" };

test( whoami.bind( ctxA));
test( whoami.bind( ctxB));
test( whoami.bind( window));
```

Comment: нет нельзя, он доступен только изнутри

Comment: @Grundy читал в вопросах 2010 года, что нельзя. Думал, может, ситауция изменилась, жизнь налаживается? ES6, voodoo..

Comment: не, мне кажется никогда нельзя будет получить, да и смысла особого нет

Comment: Объект-контекст выполнения кода - это "свалка", в которой лежат параметры функции, объект переменных (временное дерево, на котором отрабатывает код функции), свойство this, свойство scope. Каждый раз, когда надо интерпретатору взять переменную, он идет ее смотреть в объект-контекст ТЕКУЩИЙ, если нет его там, смотрит, куда ссылается свойство scope, идет в этот объект-стек  и "берет" ниже лежащий в стеке объект-контекст выполнения (или объект Closure берет, если он попадается). Объект-контекст выполнения кода - это АБСТРАКТНЫЙ объект (модель работы).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли узнать контекст переданной функции?

Нет, нельзя.

---

#### Применительно к результату функции *bind*.

Данная функция возвращает [не совсем обычную функцию](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects), а объект-обертку. В возвращаемом объекте эта функция устанавливает *внутреннее поле* `[[BoundThis]]` - которое недоступно из кода. И только при вызове, значение этого поля передается в функцию и становится доступно через ключевое слово `this`.

Answer (score -2):

Объект-контекст выполнения кода - это "свалка", в которой лежат параметры функции, объект переменных (временное дерево, на котором отрабатывает код функции), свойство `this`, свойство `scope`. Каждый раз, когда надо интерпретатору взять переменную, он идет ее смотреть в объект-контекст ТЕКУЩИЙ, если нет его там, смотрит, куда ссылается свойство `scope`, идет в этот объект-стек и "берет" ниже лежащий в стеке объект-контекст выполнения (или объект `Closure` берет, если он попадается).

Объект-контекст выполнения кода - это АБСТРАКТНЫЙ объект (модель работы). Если код глобальный, то такой объект-контекст выполнения кода называется Global. Если код - код внутри функции, то такой объект-контекст выполнения кода называется Local.

Этот объект нельзя "узнать", можно только пользоваться переменными и параметрами, которые в нем лежат.

Свойство `this`объекта-контекста выполнения кода функции указывает на объект из BOM, в котором есть свойство, которое ссылается на эту функцию (указывает на объект, в котором эта функция лежит).